# Join columns with certain values (and replace)

Tags: mysql

Consider a table that looks like this:

```
**************************
* Col1 *** Col2 *** Col3 * 
--------------------------
*  0   ***  1   ***  0   *
*  0   ***  0   ***  0   *
*  1   ***  1   ***  0   *
*  1   ***  1   ***  1   *
**************************
```

How could I join (for example) the last row with each field containing "1" translated into something?

So for the first row, it would return something like: "Yes" (omitting the ones that isn't "1"). Or for the last row: "Yes, Yes, Yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(Col1=1,'Yes', 'No'), IF(Col2=1,'Yes', 'No'), IF(Col3=1,'Yes', 'No') FROM tbl;
```

Replace `'NO'` with `0` if you don't want No.

**ANSWER MODIFICATION TO REFLECT QUESTION:**

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', IF(Col1=1,'Yes',NULL), IF(Col2=1, 'Yes', NULL), IF(Col3=1, 'Yes', NULL) ) as formatedText FROM tbl;
```

Comment: I need to separate non-"0" values with a comma and translate the ones that are "1".

Comment: Try this then:
`SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', IF(Col1=1,'Yes',''), IF(Col2=1, 'Yes', ''), IF(Col3=1, 'Yes', '') ) as formatedText FROM tbl;`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(TRIM(CONCAT(IF(Col1=1,'Yes ',''), IF(Col2=1,'Yes ',''), IF(Col3=1,'Yes ',''))), ' ', ', ') AS translation
FROM
    oneyes
```